How can co_spawn be used with co_await?
I am currently creating multiple task_sub() at the beginning of the task_main() function, and waiting for these task_sub() to end before exiting task_main(). There is only one thread. What should I do?
Is there any way to achieve this requirement? Note: task_main() and task_sub()are not at the same level, and task_sub()must be created in task_main().
asio 1.31.0

awaitable<void> task_sub()
{
    // TODO something
}

awaitable<void> task_main()
{
    printf("task_main begin\n");
    
    // create some task_sub and execute
    auto task1 = co_spawn(co_await this_coro::executor, task_sub(), xxxxxx?);
    auto task2 = co_spawn(co_await this_coro::executor, task_sub(), xxxxxx?);

    // main loop
    // TODO something

    // waiting task
    co_await task1;
    co_await task2;

    printf("task_main end\n");
}


I have tried using use_future to wait for the task to end, but it does not support co_await and task1.wait() is sync and blocked, which will block the main loop.
awaitable<void> task_main()
{
    printf("task_main begin\n");

    // create some task_sub and execute
    //
    std::future<void> task1 = co_spawn(co_await this_coro::executor, task_sub(), use_future);
    std::future<void> task2 = co_spawn(co_await this_coro::executor, task_sub(), use_future);

    // main loop
    // TODO something

    // waiting task
    //co_await task1;
    //co_await task2;

    //is blocked
    task1.wait();
    task2.wait();

    printf("task_main end\n");
}


I have also tried using channel, it can work, but it's not beautiful

//...
#include <asio/experimental/channel.hpp>

using exit_channel = asio::experimental::channel<void(asio::error_code)>;

awaitable<void> task_sub(exit_channel& channel)
{
    // TODO something

    //end
    co_await channel.async_send(error_code{});
}

awaitable<void> task_main()
{
    printf("task_main begin\n");

    auto ctx = co_await this_coro::executor;

    // create some task_sub and execute
    exit_channel task1_channel(ctx, 1);
    exit_channel task2_channel(ctx, 1);
    co_spawn(ctx, task_sub(task1_channel), detached);
    co_spawn(ctx, task_sub(task2_channel), detached);

    // main loop
    // TODO something

    // waiting task
    co_await task1_channel.async_receive();
    co_await task2_channel.async_receive();

    printf("task_main end\n");
}


And co_spawn(,,use_awaitable), it won't start executing at co_spawn, so it's not what you want.

Like I answered previously on the question you deleted, you can use use_promise:
Live On Coliru¹
#include <asio.hpp>
#include <asio/experimental/promise.hpp>
#include <asio/experimental/use_promise.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
using asio::awaitable;
using asio::experimental::use_promise;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
namespace this_coro = asio::this_coro;

awaitable<void> delay(auto dur) {
    co_await asio::steady_timer{co_await this_coro::executor, dur}.async_wait();
}

awaitable<void> task_sub(char const* caption, int n, auto ival) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("task_sub '%s' %d\n", caption, i);
        co_await delay(ival);
    }
}

awaitable<void> task_main()
{
    printf("task_main begin\n");
    
    auto ex = co_await this_coro::executor;
    // create some task_sub and execute
    auto task1 = co_spawn(ex, task_sub("task1", 5, 500ms), use_promise);
    auto task2 = co_spawn(ex, task_sub("task2", 4, 750ms), use_promise);

    // main loop
    // TODO something
    co_await task_sub("task_main", 3, 1000ms);

    printf("task_main wait\n");

    co_await std::move(task1);
    co_await std::move(task2);

    printf("task_main end\n");
}

int main() {
    asio::io_context ctx;
    co_spawn(ctx, task_main(), asio::detached);
    ctx.run();
}

See it live:

¹ using Boost Asio online, because it doesn't have standalone Asio
Parallel Groups
I'd still suggest parallel groups with awaitable operators for syntactic sugar:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/promise.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/use_promise.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/awaitable_operators.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::awaitable;
using asio::experimental::use_promise;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using namespace asio::experimental::awaitable_operators;
namespace this_coro = asio::this_coro;

awaitable<void> delay(auto dur) {
    co_await asio::steady_timer{co_await this_coro::executor, dur}.async_wait();
}

awaitable<void> task_sub(char const* caption, int n, auto ival) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("task_sub '%s' %d\n", caption, i);
        co_await delay(ival);
    }
    printf("task_sub '%s' done\n", caption);
}

awaitable<void> task_main() {
    printf("task_main begin\n");
    
    auto ex = co_await this_coro::executor;
    co_await (                              //
        task_sub("task1", 5, 500ms)         //
        && task_sub("task2", 4, 750ms)      //
        && task_sub("task_main", 3, 1000ms) //
    );

    printf("task_main end\n");
}

int main() {
    asio::io_context ctx;
    co_spawn(ctx, task_main(), asio::detached);
    ctx.run();
}

Printing
task_main begin
task_sub 'task1' 0
task_sub 'task2' 0
task_sub 'task_main' 0
task_sub 'task1' 1
task_sub 'task2' 1
task_sub 'task_main' 1
task_sub 'task1' 2
task_sub 'task1' 3
task_sub 'task2' 2
task_sub 'task_main' 2
task_sub 'task1' 4
task_sub 'task2' 3
task_sub 'task1' done
task_sub 'task_main' done
task_sub 'task2' done
task_main end


Added the awaitable-operators version, which I still think is more elegant and relevant than doing things manually. Especially when cancellation of one task should also abort some others. https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1abab05e76c03d0

Thank you very much for your patient answer! Due to the inability to cancel task_sub in my business, I cannot use awaitable operators, but use_promise is what I need!

I expect awaitable operators work fine without cancellation
